# Create a class for CSS code

Tags: html, css

Create Custom CSS Class for below mentioned piece of code. I am using this code to display table in WordPress. Anyone, Please Guide me to create a separate CSS class for this piece of code. Thanks in advance

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}
table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This clearly is a troll question. And if it is not, it obviously lacks the most basic research effort. -1

Comment: @connexo i edited the question please remove put on hold

Answer (score 1):

Give your table a class like `<table class="sep-table">` then do this to your css

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
.sep-table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.sep-table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
.sep-table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}
.sep-table th,
.sep-table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}
.sep-table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sep-table {
    border: 0;
  }
  .sep-table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  .sep-table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  .sep-table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  .sep-table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .sep-table td:before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .sep-table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: this code not working.

Comment: did you give your table the class 'sep-table' ? you should really go though the basics of html and css, lots of tutorials and helpful sites around. check out w3schools